# PostgreSQL: duplication by one command

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, command

My friends. I have postgresql db on server and on local machine. I know parameters of the remote server and local server, and I need by one command to duplicate from one to the local. I sought how do it in the internet, but didn't find. Need your help.

I have Ubuntu on local computer, and all I have about remote server is: a host, a port, a username, a password, a database etc. And know all about mine =))))

It's not real problem, but today is first day when I work with postgresql, and I need copy already.

P.S. Sorry my English.

Comment: Yes, it is. How mark the question like closed?

Comment: A moderator will do that.